# How can I search all files ending with the file extension `.feature` on Github?

Tags: github

I'm looking for examples of `.feature` files written with the [Gherkin syntax](https://cucumber.io/docs/gherkin/).

I tried this query:

https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=extension%3Afeature&ref=simplesearch

But there are no results.

Comment: Try https://github.com/search?q=feature+extension%3Afeature

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Just enter

```
path:*.feature
```

into the search bar.

Comment: I am left wondering why  it does not work in the github api but does work in the github search bar.

Answer (score 9):

According to GitHub's help page on [Searching Code](https://help.github.com/en/github/searching-for-information-on-github/searching-code), under [Considerations for code search](https://help.github.com/en/github/searching-for-information-on-github/searching-code#considerations-for-code-search), it is mentioned that:

> Except with `filename` searches, you must always include at least one search term when searching source code. For example, searching for `language:javascript` is not valid, while `amazing language:javascript` is.

So, just searching for `extension:feature` will not work. You need to use at least one search term. For example, `Feature extension:feature`, where `Feature` is a search term.

You can also search by language, by using, for example, `Feature language:Gherkin`.